# save image in folder and path in mysql database

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Project Title"/><br />
 <input type="text" id="vurl" placeholder="If You have any video about project write your video url path here" style="width:435px;"/><br />
<textarea id="prjdesc" name="prjdesc" rows="20" cols="80" style="border-style:groove;box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #888888;"placeholder="Please describe Your Project"></textarea>

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="update"/>
</form>
```

On click submit the data is storing in database and displaying using Ajax call
this is my js code:

```
$("#update").click(function(e) {
      alert("update");
      e.preventDefault();
      var ttle = $("#title").val();
      alert(ttle);
      var text = $("#prjdesc").val(); 
      var vurl = $("#vurl").val();
      var img = $("#file").val();
      alert(vurl);
      var dataString = 'param='+text+'&param1='+vurl+'&param2='+ttle+'&param3='+img;
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:dataString,
        url:'insert.php',
        success:function(id) {
          alert(id);
          window.location ="another.php?id="+id;;
        }
      });
    });
```

here i am storing data using insert.php and displaying using another.php
but when coming to the image part i dont understand how to store image in folder and path in db, i mean i am bit confused to integrate code in insert.php

insert.php

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="geny";
$tbl_name="project_details";


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $name = $_POST['param'];
 $video = $_POST['param1'];
 $title = $_POST['param2'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (title, content, video_url) VALUES ('$title','$name','$video')";

 if(mysql_query($sql)) {
echo mysql_insert_id();

 } else {
  echo "Cannot Insert";
 }
```

if i do separate then the image is storing in folder..

if i do separate then the form code is:

```
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
 else
{
   echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
   echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 // echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $tmp = "C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  echo $tmp;
  }
  }
}
else
 {
 echo "Invalid file";
 }
?>
```

this is working perfectly...

my question is how to integrate this code in insert.php...
please help me...

Answer (score 1):

This code would work fine without the use of javascript. But make sure to change the directory and the table name and fields on line "2" and "66" resp.

We will create a hidden textarea which will create the datastring and we will get all the params using $_GET

```
<script>
$("#update").click(function(e) {
  alert("update");
  e.preventDefault();
  var ttle = $("#title").val();
  alert(ttle);
  var text = $("#prjdesc").val(); 
  var vurl = $("#vurl").val();
  var img = $("#file").val();
  alert(vurl);
  var textareastring = $('#string').val();
  var dataString = 'textareastring' = textareastring;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'insert.php?param='+text+'&param1='+vurl+'&param2='+ttle+'&param3='+img',
    success:function(id) {
      alert(id);
      window.location ="another.php?id="+id;;
    }
  });
});
</script>
<textarea id="string" style="display:none;">aa</textarea>
<?php
$name = $_GET['param3']; 
// The name.n ow replacing all the $file_name with $name
$url = $_GET['param1'];
$text = $_GET['param'];
$title = $_GET['param2'];
$upload_dir = $url;
$num_files = 1;
//the file size in bytes.
$size_bytes =104857600; //51200 bytes = 50KB.
//Extensions you want files uploaded limited to.
$limitedext = array(".tif",".gif",".png",".jpeg",".jpg");
//check if the directory exists or not.
if (!is_dir("$upload_dir")) {
  die ("Error: The directory <b>($upload_dir)</b> doesn't exist.  ");
}
//check if the directory is writable.
if (!is_writeable("$upload_dir")){
  die ("Error: The directory <b>($upload_dir)</b> .  ");
}
if (isset($_POST['upload_form'])){

   echo "<h3>Upload results:</h3><br>";

   //do a loop for uploading files based on ($num_files) number of files.
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_files; $i++) {

       //define variables to hold the values.
       $new_file = $_FILES['file'.$i];
       $name = $new_file['name'];
       //to remove spaces from file name we have to replace it with "_".
       $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
       $file_tmp = $new_file['tmp_name'];
       $file_size = $new_file['size'];

       #-----------------------------------------------------------#
       # this code will check if the files was selected or not.    #
       #-----------------------------------------------------------#

       if (!is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)) {
          //print error message and file number.
          echo "File: Not selected.<br><br>";
       }else{
             #-----------------------------------------------------------#
             # this code will check file extension                       #
             #-----------------------------------------------------------#

             $ext = strrchr($name,'.');
             if (!in_array(strtolower($ext),$limitedext)) {
                echo "File $i: ($name) Wrong file extension.  <br><br>";
             }else{
                   #-----------------------------------------------------------#
                   # this code will check file size is correct                 #
                   #-----------------------------------------------------------#

                   if ($file_size > $size_bytes){
   echo "File : ($name) Faild to upload. File must be no larger than <b>100   MB</b> in size.";
                   }else{
                #-----------------------------------------------------------#
                # this code check if file is Already EXISTS.                #
                #-----------------------------------------------------------#
                         if(file_exists($upload_dir.$name)){
                             echo "File: ($name) already exists.    <br><br>";
                         }else{
                               #-------------------------------#
                               # this function will upload the files.         #
                               #-------------------------------#
                               if     (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$upload_dir.$name)) {
                                   $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2) VALUES('$field1', '$field2');";
                                   echo "File: ($name) has been uploaded successfully." . "<img src='uploads/$name'/>";  

                               }else{
                                    echo "File: Faild to upload.  <br><br>";
                               }#end of (move_uploaded_file).

                         }#end of (file_exists).

                   }#end of (file_size).

             }#end of (limitedext).

       }#end of (!is_uploaded_file).

   }#end of (for loop).
   # print back button.
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //else if the form didn't submitted then show it.
}else{
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\" enctype=\"multipart/form-        data\">";
       // show the file input field based on($num_files).
       for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_files; $i++) {
           echo "<b>Image: </b><input type=\"file\" size=\"70\"             name=\"file". $i ."\" style=\"width:45%\">";
       }
echo " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"$size_bytes\">
       <input type=\"submit\" name=\"upload_form\" value=\"Upload\">
       </form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: this code os working fine...i dont have problems with this code..what i want is i want to integrate this code in insert.php

Comment: k so replace the $file_name wherever you find and replace it with $name that you get using post. This would save your file with that name. I am editing it to make it more specific. Make sure you see that.

Comment: but i am getting 4 params from js file..how can i differenciate which one having image file

Comment: k make it ['param3']. I have seen your code. You have used  param3 for img. I have again edited the code see it.

Comment: Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=

Comment: I have edited the code. Now I have included all the params you have used.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['upload_form']))...from where u got this 'upload_form'....plese tell me..i need to change the name here??

Comment: this is th name of the submit button on 4th last line .

Comment: it sanitizes the code. It checks if the button has been clicked or not. If user has clicked the button it checks the file name, size and other info required an shows what it got.

Comment: ok sorry i saw the submit button...but the thing is the if part in not executing...it is going to the else part and printing echoed form

Comment: is it after the click of the button .

Comment: still its not executing the if part "if (isset($_POST['upload_form']))"

Comment: Is that code working? I don't think so. To get the image temp path you need to submit the form and get it from $_FILES array. How could you do it in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to call insert.php after submit button was clicked, in this line

```php
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you have to add this

```php
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

/*dont use path like this C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/ becuase you are working at localhost server*/
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){

    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

}else{

    $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"]
    $filePath = "upload/" . $file;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filePath)){

        /*prepare sql query here and insert*/
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2) VALUES('$field1', '$field2');";
        if(mysql_query($sql)){

            echo "File saved in database successfully <strong>{$filePath}</strong>";

        }else{

            echo "File not uploaded there are an error <strong>{$filePath}</strong>";

        }


    }else{

        echo "File not uploaded there are an error <strong>{$file}</strong>";

    }


} ?>
```

try this code if you have any doubt or code not working fine then ask me again.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for u r reply..actually i want the code to write in insert.php...pls check my insert.php..where i am getting form elements from javascript file...so how cani get the image file form javascript file and how to check the image file

Comment: hii i edited the code you can see my insert.php file...tell me now how to integrate imageupload code in insert.php..please