# Get the data from two tables using id

Tags: php

I want to display the elements from two tables using onclick Id.
These are my tables:

Project_tech:

```
project_tech_id  project_tech_name
        1            Mechanical
        2            Civil
        3            Computers
```

project_detail:

```
id      title       content       project_tech_id
 1     sample        abcd              3
 2     sample2       efgh              1
 3     sample3       xyz               3
```

there is a relation between two tables using project_tech_id.The values are inserting into project_detail using form.
now i want to display the title,content,project_tech_name where project_tect_id=3 from project_detai table means i want two display two columns data...
how to display this using one query..
Actually iam using this query but i am getting error:

```
$prj_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,
    pd.title, 
    pd.content,
    pd.video_url,
    FROM
      project_details pd,
      project_tech pt
      WHERE
      pt.project_tech_Id = pd.project_tech_Id AND
      pt.project_tech_Id in" .$prj_id);
```

pls...help me...

Comment: Look in to MySQL's join function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnerable ([sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Secondly, don't use deprecated [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/mysql) use either [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) with [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). And lastly, you're missing space after `in` here: `pt.project_tech_Id in " .$prj_id);` that leads to invalid sql query (assuming `$prj_id === '(someIdsHereSeparatedByComma)'`).

Comment: @PLB:ok i ll use PDO..still i m getting the same error after giving the space afet in..

Comment: @user2330772 `var_dump($prj_id)` and see what's inside. Debug your code, please. :)

Comment: @PLB:thanks i got it removing comma aftre pd.video_url...what i want is how to display two tables data

Comment: @user2330772 [Here's example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2664b/1). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to execute it

```
mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,pd.title,pd.content,pd.video_url
    FROM
      project_details pd Left Join project_tech pt
      ON
      pt.project_tech_Id = pd.project_tech_Id AND
      pt.project_tech_Id = " .$prj_id);
```

Comment: Thanks i got it...but could u tell me actually i m getting only one column data...but i want whose id =3..means two columns data

Comment: Hi please print the result what your getting i think it will be execute properly it getting two rows data but it might show the only single row that to may be first one right once u try to print_r($result) u can find out the two records

Comment: i m printing like this:$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];

Comment: while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
} see like this u get the o/p what ur want

Comment: ya i got...but displaying single row...i want display multiples rows

Comment: u getting data from database then play with that data

Comment: actually it displaying like array...i dont want like this..i have a bit knowledge in displaying data from db...so pls help me to do this

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Mechanical
    [1] => Complaint Management System
    [2] => This web application is managed and executed by RI -TECH. RI-TECH pune is leading IT Training company provided training to more than 5000/- students from last five years.
    [3] => http://localhost/WebsiteTemplate4/
)
Array
(
    [0] => Mechanical
    [1] => sample
    [2] => some content here...
    [3] => http://localhost/WebsiteTemplate3/gallery.php?id=2
)

Comment: that is the output i m getting after excuting the query

Comment: <td><?php echo $res[0];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res[2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res[3];?></td>

Comment: ya..i tried like that...when i say $res[0] then two values are coming

Comment: one row data in one table..another one in another table

Comment: separate depending upon the data which is getting in array as seen previous like

Comment: hii if u know this question answer pls tell me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938113/save-image-in-folder-and-path-in-mysql-database..  fallow this link

Answer (score 1):

You should use = instead of in

Comment: why? both are comparison operators .. so why this = better than in?

Comment: Thanks i got it...but could u tell me actually i m getting only one column data...but i want whose id =3..means two columns data...

Answer (score 0):

Using **JOIN** you can do it like this:

```
$prj_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,
            pd.title, pd.content, pd.video_url
            FROM project_details pd JOIN project_tech pt
            ON pd.project_tech_id = pt.project_tech_id
            WHERE pt.project_tech_Id = {$prj_id}");
```

Comment: Thanks i got it...but could u tell me actually i m getting only one column data...but i want whose id =3..means two columns data

Comment: what you mean with "one column data"?

Comment: i m getting only one column data using my query where project_tech_id=3..but u can see my project_detail table there are two columns with that id

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,
    pd.title, 
    pd.content,
    pd.video_url
    FROM
      project_details pd,
      project_tech pt
      WHERE
      pt.project_tech_Id = pd.project_tech_Id 
      AND
      pt.project_tech_Id in (" .$prj_id.")");
```

or

```
pt.project_tech_Id = " .$prj_id);
```

// I just removed comma before `From` clause also

Comment: Thanks i got it...but could u tell me actually i m getting only one column data...but i want whose id =3..means two columns data

Comment: @user2330772 what is the value of $prj_id? The result depends on that value.

Comment: its value is 3...so i want to print two columns data..there are two columns with that id in project_detail table

Comment: @user2330772 from the answer you gave to user1578358 i can see you are only showing the first row of $sql (the query result). try to loop through it like `while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql)){ echo $row['id']; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

your query can be : this is a optimized on as it uses LEFT JOIN.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,
    pd.title, 
    pd.content,
    pd.video_url,
    FROM project_details pd
     LEFT JOIN project_tech pt 
      ON pt.project_tech_Id = pd.project_tech_Id
    WHERE  pt.project_tech_Id = {$prj_id} ");
```

Comment: Thanks i got it...but could u tell me actually i m getting only one column data...but i want whose id =3..means two columns data

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query there is field name "pd.video_url", which is not in your table structure and one extra comma(,) after this field value.

2nd issue is, use "=" instead of "in"

If there is multiple "project_tech_Id", then you can use "in" like

```
$prj_id = (1,4,7,2);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt.project_tech_name,
    pd.title, 
    pd.content,
    pd.video_url,
    FROM
      project_details pd,
      project_tech pt
      WHERE
      pt.project_tech_Id = pd.project_tech_Id AND
      pt.project_tech_Id in(" .$prj_id .")".);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"SELECT 
project_tech.project_tech_name,
project_detail.title, 
project_detail.content,
project_detail.video_url

FROM project_tech
JOIN project_details
ON 
project_tech.project_tech_Id = project_details.project_tech_Id 
AND
project_tech.project_tech_Id = $prj_id"
```